# Does cumin contain curcumin? If not, where does the name come from?

Tags: chemistry

According to Wikipedia, curcumin was originally isolated from tumeric.  However, I haven't been able to find why it was  named curcumin or whether or not it cumin is currently known to contain it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the opening of [the Wikipedia article on curcumin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curcumin) you presumably saw:

> Curcumin is a bright yellow chemical produced by some plants. It is the principal curcuminoid of turmeric (**Curcuma longa**), a member of the ginger family (Zingiberaceae).

(emphasis mine)

As for [the Curcuma genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curcuma):

> The name comes from the Sanskrit kuṅkuma, referring to turmeric.

So, nothing to do with cumin - just a bit of a coincidence from turning "curcuma" into "curcumin".

Comment: In Arabic (and Hebrew) turmeric is called curcum... Probably also Persian

Comment: And in german turmeric is called Kurkuma. Cumin supposedly stems from arabic "kammun" (which is a warm drink including cumin) or hebrew "kammon" (which is a little unclear, maybe refering to preservation/storage).

Comment: Also worth noting the etymology of [cumin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cumin): “cumin (n.) Old English *cymen,* from Latin *cuminum,* from Greek *kyminon,* cognate with Hebrew *kammon,* Arabic *kammun.*”.